# Trying to babel either JavaScript OR TypeScript files for use in Node environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, babeljs, tsc

Our node environment requires that our JavaScript files be babeled. This is easy enough.

The difficult part is that we have `.js, .jsx, .ts, .tsx` files and this won't change.

Is there anything I could do to get the TypeScript files converted into JavaScript, and then have all the `.js/.jsx` files go through babel?

My current command:

`nodemon app.js --exec babel-node --presets env,stage-2,react`

I know that I need TypeScript to be converted somewhere in there.

Any ideas?

Node version: 8.11.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With babel 7 you can use the [typescript preset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-typescript). You still need typescript to do the actual type checking, just the compilation to js will now be done by babel.

Here's what a simple setup might look like:

1. `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-typescript`

Update the rest of the toolchain to babel 7 too (e.g. `babel-cli` to `@babel/cli @babel/core`, `babel-preset-env` to `@babel/preset-env` etc.)

2. Add `"noEmit": true` to your `tsconfig.json`. This ensures typescript only does type checking and doesn't output js.
3. Add `--extensions '.js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx'` to your command.

So your command becomes:

```
nodemon app.js --exec babel-node --presets @babel/env,@babel/stage-2,@babel/react,@babel/typescript --extensions '.js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx'
```